# How do I write a Java code for date picker where I can choose random dates every time

Tags: automated-testing

I have a date picker option on my website where I have to pick up a date for after 2 weeks from current date, how do I do that using java programming language?

Comment: Do you know how to do it in some other programming language?

Comment: Can you how that site so I can see data picker and then can help you to get value from date picker.

Answer (score 1):

The below code should give you two weeks from the current date

```
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    c.setTime(new Date()); // Use today date
    c.add(Calendar.DATE, 14); // Adding 14 days which is two weeks from the current date
    String output = sdf.format(c.getTime());
```

Selecting this date from the date picker will require knowing what type of date picker is used in your website.

Check out the below link for more on how to select if using selenium
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21398575/select-a-date-from-date-picker-using-selenium-webdriver